# External CSS in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Is it **OK to include an external CSS into a WP plugin** by developer?

- against the policies
- ethical? (loading resources from your server)
- if public resource e.g. BootstrapCDN
- not advised (this one is obvious, dependency+etc)

Thank you!